# Insert fetching the array data to new database

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I am trying to SELECT rows of data from MYSQL and to INSERT it as rows of array to NEW DATABASE with some additional data.
Please help, this script is not working:

```
// there is some script and here goes fetching-inserting script:
<?php
include ('connection.php');
$query="SELECT * from savatcha where mem_id='$mem_id' ORDER BY nomination ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result); 
mysql_close();
$i=0;
$grand_total=0;
while ($i < $num) 
{
  $savatcha_id=mysql_result($result, $i, "savatcha_id");
  $s_mem_id=mysql_result($result, $i, "s_mem_id");
  $mem_id=mysql_result($result, $i, "mem_id");
  $tovar_id=mysql_result($result, $i, "tovar_id");
  $nomination=mysql_result($result, $i, "nomination");
  $price=mysql_result($result,$i,"price");
  $quantity=mysql_result($result,$i,"quantity");
  $total_row=$price * $quantity;
  $grand_total += $total_row;
?>
<?php
  include ('order_connection.php');
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_list(order_id, s_mem_id, mem_id, firm_name, grand_total, order_method, order_date)VALUES('$order_id', '$s_mem_id', '$mem_id', '$firm_name', '$grand_total', 'Bank hisob raqami orqali', '$date')");
  mysql_close();
?>
<?php
  ++$i;
}
?>
```

Comment: Which script? You should at least put along with the question, what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Please add a single while line before the code so that SO displays the code snippet

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of getting data from database, load them into `php` array and inserting it back to another table you can simply use this `mysql` query.

```
INSERT INTO databasename2.tablename2(field1,field2,fieldn,fielda,fieldb) SELECT field1,field2,fieldn,valuea,valueb FROM databasename1.tablename1
```

Comment: But how to INSERT along additional not relevant data with that code?

Comment: valuea and valueb in above ex are irrelevant data which you can pass from php